# Naming conventions in blue/green deployment with different environments

Tags: deployment, production-environment, naming, blue-green-deployment

In our deployment we have three environments: testing, staging, and production.
We recently introduced a blue-green setup so that we now have blue-production, blue-staging, green-production, green-staging and testing.

We now wonder about the naming of these "colors". Intuitively I'd go for blue/green-environment but this is currently in use.

Is there a standard or common naming schema in this setup? The best I came up with is to label "testing, staging, and production" as "stages" and "blue/green" as "environments".
Exemplary usage: "what is the status of the production stage in the blue environment?".
Is there a better alternative?

Comment: Did my answer help? What naming convention did you end up using?

Comment: Hey @BenSmith, sorry for replying only now, I was on vacation. Your reply helps in so far that we could say that one of the two environments is live and one idles but this is a dynamic naming scheme and is therefore a bit confusing. The naming scheme we're currently using is the one I posted in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The use of Blue and Green can be ambiguous for users unfamiliar with this naming convention.

Instead of using Blue/Green I'd suggest using Live/Idle to be more explicit (as documented [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html)).